# Does GRPC ManagedChannel use DNS-RR for load balancing?

Tags: java, grpc

When creating a channel like this

```
ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("mybackend", 6565)
```

And `mybackend` is a DNS A record with multiple IP addresses.

Does GRPC round-robin between the records or does it just stick to one for the lifetime of the channel?

If not, would it work if I do?

```
ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget("dns:///mybackend:6565")
```

Or is this capability just not available?

Answer (score 1):

[`NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(SocketAddress)`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/netty/NettyChannelBuilder.html#forAddress-java.net.SocketAddress-) is the API that can only access a single IP, due to InetSocketAddress's eager resolution.

`forAddress(String, int)` was retrofit to use `forTarget(String)` internally. So it is a convenience and converts to something similar to `forTarget(host + ":" + port)`, but with some extra logic to handle IPv6 literals. The "dns:///" prefix is added to target strings when they fail to parse. See [the `forTarget()` docs](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.html#forTarget-java.lang.String-) for both details. So it is essentially equivalent to using `forTarget("dns:///mybackend:6565")`.

gRPC, by default, doesn't round-robin over multiple addresses. By default it does "pick-first" which stops on the first working address (potentially choosing a different address when reconnecting). You can change that via a service config or [`defaultLoadBalancingPolicy("round_robin")`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.html#defaultLoadBalancingPolicy-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Do I need dns:/// in order to avail of round_robin? or will it work for forAddress?

Comment: round_robin will work with forAddress(). In the answer I explained how forAddress(String, int) gets converted into forTarget() with dns:///

Comment: where do we get a list of load balancing policies?

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/2d4f3c56001cd1e1f85734b2f7c5ce5f2797c38a/doc/load-balancing.md#load-balancing-policies mentions "the big three", pick_first, round_robin, grpclb. xDS has lots of policies, but they are currently just for its use. (priority and least_request are probably the ones that could be reused. https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/pull/8739)